# unity3d C# Waypoints

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я просмотрел, все. что нашел по теме, и везде объект ходит по точкам, последовательность которых перебирается в цикле.
Можно добавить случайности. У меня несколько иная задача.
Объект стоит на точке и игрок должен выбрать следующую из двух - трех предлагаемых. Причем это уже не последовательно по массиву.Это ближайшие точки по пути, к которым путь - отрезок прямой. На следующей точке все повторяется. 
Мне кажется хорошей идеей поворачивать объект лицом к нужной точке. Но как сказать ему, чтобы он шел к ближайшей точке перед собой. и на ней стал?

Comment: Уберите лишнюю информацию из вопроса. Останется только "Как сказать объекту, чтобы он шел к ближайшей точке перед собой и на ней встал?"

Answer (score 1):

В системах хождения по точкам можно взять алгоритмы по плавной траектории движения, если у вас конечно живой объект, для робота вполне сойдет и ломаный путь когда доехал до точки, остановился и дальше поехал. 
Если вспомнить институт, то ваша задача очень напоминает транспортную задачу по поиску кратчайшего пути. Посмотрите примеры с PathFinder. А еще вам понадобиться StateMachine чтобы менять поведение объекта при переходе из одного состояния в другое. Вопрос на самом деле большой и в одной строчке не ответить, но не такой уж сложный.

Comment: чтобы не было заблуждений, игрок выводит человека из лабиринта.gameObject.transform.position += Wayp.transform.forward;Если объект направлен на точку, по этой команде он пойдет на нее?

Comment: не факт что пойдет. вы смещаете позицию объекта  по направлению куда ваша точка пути направлена, а смотреть она может бог знает куда. лучше через LookAt(http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) целиться на точку и потом в самом объекте который движется просто прибавлять к позиции Transform.forward

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveToWaypoints : MonoBehaviour {

public List<Transform> waypoints = new List<Transform>();
bool isBusy = false;
int currentStep = 0;

void Update() {
    if (waypoints != null && !isBusy) {
        Move();
    }
}

void Move() {
    isBusy = true;
    Vector3 targetPosition = waypoints[currentStep].position;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime * 10);
    transform.LookAt(waypoints[currentStep]);
    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPosition) < 1) {
        isBusy = false;
        currentStep++;
    }
  }
 }
```

Попробуйте этот код. Повесьте этот скрипт на свой объект. Создайте пустые GameObject, они будут точками WayPoint, перекиньте их в лист. P.S. писал на скорую руку;)